# AutoFill Formula (running across spreadsheet) - Google Sheets / Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to change my code below to autofill the formula across the page - not autofill down

you can see in the 2 images below I can add the formula to N527 but cannot autofill across the page with code - which is what i am looking for.

So images are before and after of what i am looking to accomplish

```
function LastColumn(){
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var LastColumn = spreadsheet.getLastColumn();
//spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('MASTER'), true);
spreadsheet.getRange('N527').activate();
spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=sum(N497*N498*N499)/100/250');
var destinationRange = spreadsheet.getActiveRange().offset(0, 0, LastColumn -526);
spreadsheet.getRange("N527:BK527").copyTo(destinationRange);  
}
```

[image: Before AutoFill]

[image: After AutoFill]

I couldnt get the attached code to work

I am trying to Autofill N527 across to AK527 - IF THE CELL ABOVE HAS DATA.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I cannot understand about `IF THE CELL ABOVE HAS DATA.`. I apologize for my poor English skill. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: Hi Tanaike - if the cell above (row 526 ) contains the word "carton" then fill with the formula. So Column O at line 527 should have the formula  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=sum(O497*O498*)499)/100/250'); etc etc

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the result you expect, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to put the formula of `=sum(N497*N498*N499)/100/250` from the cell "N527" to the column direction.
- In this case, when the row 526 of the same column has the value of `carton`, you want to put the formula.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```
function LastColumn() {
  var sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set the sheet name.
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var range = sheet.getRange('N526:526');
  var ranges = range.getValues()[0].reduce((ar, r, i) => {
    if (r.toLowerCase() == "carton") ar.push(range.offset(1, i, 1, 1).getA1Notation());
    return ar;
  }, []);
  sheet.getRangeList(ranges).setFormulaR1C1('=sum(R[-30]C[0]*R[-29]C[0]*R[-28]C[0])/100/250');  // This formula is like `=sum(N497*N498*N499)/100/250`.
}
```

- In this case, at first, the cells "N526:526" are checked whether the cell has the value of `carton`. And, when the cell has the value, the formula is put to the row 527.

  - I used RangeList for this.

#### References:

- [getRangeList(a1Notations)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangelista1notations)
- [setFormulaR1C1(formula) of Class RangeList](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range-list#setformular1c1formula)

Answer (score 0):

### You need to copy the formula from cell already containing the formula to the range to which you want to expand it

This means that your destination range should be "O527:BK527".

Sample:

```js
function autoFill(){
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('MASTER');
  var firstCell = sheet.getRange('N527');
  firstCell.setFormula('=sum(N497*N498*N499)/100/250');
  var destinationRange = sheet.getRange("O527:BK527");
  firstCell.copyTo(destinationRange);  
}
```

Comment: Thank you ziganotschka - i would only want to fill the row if the above cell contains data - in this case "carton" to find last column of data.